# Como excluir elementos de um vetor registro no Pascal

Tags: array, pascal

Estou fazendo um trabalho pro curso, e toda vez que a pessoa digitasse um valor de um índice do elemento do vetor registro, todos os dados do mesmo fossem apagados, isso seria possível? 
Se sim, como faço?

Comment: Parece-me que você quer que resolvemos o seu exercício. Se não for isso, poste tudo o que você já fez e as duvidas especificas que você teve para a resolução do problema e se for isso, poste o exercício tal qual o professor lhe pediu.

Comment: Já consegui fazer, mesmo assim obrigado ;)